# How can I return (n) closest addresses from a specific point using Google Distance Matrix?

Tags: php, google-maps-api-3, distance, google-distancematrix-api, distance-matrix

I've been researching in here and haven't found an answer so far. So here's my question:

I have several addresses on MySQL database and I need to return the 10 closest addresses from just one specific address. How do I do it?

It's not so clear on how I could measure those distances and select the 10 closest ones.

Please help me.

> Updating this post!

I found this code:

```
function codeAddress() {
    var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
    if (customerMarker) customerMarker.setMap(null);
        customerMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: results[0].geometry.location
        });
    closest = findClosestN(results[0].geometry.location,10);
        // get driving distance
        closest = closest.splice(0,3);
        calculateDistances(results[0].geometry.location, closest,3);
       } else {
         alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
      }
    });
  }

function findClosestN(pt,numberOfResults) {
   var closest = [];
   document.getElementById('info').innerHTML += "processing "+gmarkers.length+"br>";
   for (var i=0; i<gmarkers.length;i++) {
     gmarkers[i].distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(pt,gmarkers[i].getPosition());
      document.getElementById('info').innerHTML += "process "+i+":"+gmarkers[i].getPosition().toUrlValue(6)+":"+gmarkers[i].distance.toFixed(2)+"<br>";
     gmarkers[i].setMap(null);
     closest.push(gmarkers[i]);
   }
   closest.sort(sortByDist);
   return closest; 
}

function sortByDist(a,b) {
   return (a.distance- b.distance); 
}
```

As far as I could see, it's working directly on map. But I would like to how I can take more de 200 addresses from my Mysql database, compare with one single address and give an alert with the 3 closest ones. I'm sorry, I'm have no clue on how I can do it. Any help will appreciated!

Comment: Hi @Fin, based on the code I found in another post, do you think you could help me with my doubt? Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: I see you have found some code, have you tried using it?

Comment: I'm working on it...I think I may be able to find the answer, but I'll come back here to tell what's going on.